# Is it possible to apply the Dirichlet's uniform convergence test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> For a series of functions given by $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sin\left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right)$$ on some bounded nonempty set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$, is it possible to apply the Dirichlet's uniform convergence test?

I know that it converges uniformly on $A$ by Weierstrass $M$-test.

So, i have tried to focus in a partial sum of $\sin\left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right)$, thinking the idea of bounding the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{kx}$.

Unlike what i expected, nothing was gained.

Give me some advice or any help. Thank you!

Comment: Remember that $|\sin(x)|\le|x|$, so $\left|\frac1k\sin\left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right)\right|\le\left|\frac{x}{k(k+1)}\right|$

Comment: @Primavera I don't think you can bound the partial sums of $\sin \left( \frac{x}{k+1}\right)$. For large $k$ you have that $\sin \left( \frac{x}{k+1}\right) \approx \frac{x}{k+1}$ and so the series is divergent.

Comment: @robjohn, I have already proved that it converges uniformly in that way.

Comment: @PierreCarre, is it impossible, even if there is a condition that the boundedness of $A$?

Comment: @Primavera The problem is not with $x$, so the boundedness of $A$ will not matter. What I was arguing was that for a fixed $x$, lets say  $x=1$, you cannot bound the partial sums of $\sum \sin (1/(k+1))$ because it is a divergent series with positive terms. This does not mean the original series is not uniformly convergent, it just means that you cannot apply Dirichlet's test the way you were intending.

Comment: Since $$\sum_{k = 1}^{N} \sin \biggl(\frac{x}{k+1}\biggr) \sim x\log N$$ you cannot apply Dirichlet's test per se. But if you look at the proof of Dirichlet's test, you can without problem apply the proof to this case to deduce uniform convergence because $\sum \frac{\log n}{n(n+1)} < +\infty$. It pays to know the proof and not only the theorem, because the proof actually proves more than the theorem states. (The statement of the theorem would become awkwardly cumbersome if one attempted to capture what the proof yields, so there's a good reason to state the theorem as usually is done.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|\sin x| \le |x|$ for all $x$.

There is $c>0$ such that $|x| \le c$ for all $x \in A.$ Hence for $x \in A$ we get

$|\frac{1}{k}\sin (\frac{x}{k+1})| \le \frac{1}{k}\frac{|x|}{k+1} \le c \frac{1}{k(k+1)}.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I have already proved that it converges uniformly in that way. I was wondering if I could apply the Dirichlet's uniform convergence test. Just curious.